# Switch Case Assignment, none of my cases are providing an output

Tags: c, switch-statement, output

Hi we were assigned to make a program that would ask the user to input a 4 digit decimal and the program was supposed to convert it to its roman numeral equivalent. We were tasked to only use the switch case function and nothing else. I thought I had the right idea but the problem with my code is it doesn't provide an output. Below is my code, help, pointers and advice would be greatly appreciated

```
int num, A, B, C, D;    

printf("enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

D = num%10;
C = ((num%100)/10);
B = ((num%1000)/100);
A = (num/1000);

if(0<num&&num<3001)
{

    switch(A)
    {

          case '1'  : printf("M");
                      break;
          case '2'  : printf("MM");
                      break;
          case '3'  : printf("MMM"); 
                      break;    
    }

    switch(B)
    {
           B = ((num%1000)/100);

           case '1'  : printf("C");
                       break;
           case '2'  : printf("CC");
                       break;
           case '3'  : printf("CCC");
                       break;
           case '4'  : printf("CD");
                       break;
           case '5'  : printf("D");
                       break;
           case '6'  : printf("DC");
                       break;
           case '7'  : printf("DCC");
                       break;
           case '8'  : printf("DCCC");
                       break;
           case '9'  : printf("CM");
                       break;
           }

    switch(C)
    {
           C = ((num%100)/10);

           case '1'  : printf("X");
                       break;
           case '2'  : printf("XX");
                       break;
           case '3'  : printf("XXX");
                       break;
           case '4'  : printf("XL");
                       break;
           case '5'  : printf("L");
                       break;
           case '6'  : printf("LI");
                       break;
           case '7'  : printf("LII");
                       break;
           case '8'  : printf("LIII");
                       break;
           case '9'  : printf("XC");
                       break; 
    }

    switch(D)
    {
           D = num%10;

           case '1' : printf("I");
                      break;
           case '2' : printf("II");
                      break;
           case '3' : printf("III");
                      break; 
           case '4' : printf("IV");
                      break;
           case '5' : printf("V");
                      break;
           case '6' : printf("VI");
                      break;
           case '7' : printf("VII");
                      break;
           case '8' : printf("VIII");
                      break;
           case '9' : printf("IX");
                      break;      
    }  
}            

else
    printf("number out of bounds");
```

Comment: You have already calculated `B`, `C` and `D`, why do you want to do it again? And more importantly why do you want to do it *after* the variables have been used by the `switch`? And I suggest you actually print out the values of the variables, to make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: So start some debugging. Check where the program stucks.

Comment: What numbers do you expect in A? Do you expect the value 1, 2, 3 or the ASCII value?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `switch()` , each case assumes its a character `1` (as per ascii table hex value `0x31`) and when it checks with the case what your actual value will be a integer value, ie; if `num` is `1` then its hex value is also `0x1`,
so you should change the switch cases to hex values of integers

Also one more note , I think you should change `if(0<num&&num<3001)` to `if(num > 0 && num<3001)`

```
if((num > 0) && (num<3001))
{
    printf("*\n");
    switch(A)
    {

          case 1  : printf("M");
                      break;
          case 2  : printf("MM");
                      break;
          case 3  : printf("MMM"); 
                      break;    
    }

    switch(B)
    {
           B = ((num%1000)/100);

           case 1  : printf("C");
                       break;
           case 2  : printf("CC");
                       break;
           case 3  : printf("CCC");
                       break;
           case 4  : printf("CD");
                       break;
           case 5  : printf("D");
                       break;
           case 6  : printf("DC");
                       break;
           case 7  : printf("DCC");
                       break;
           case 8  : printf("DCCC");
                       break;
           case 9  : printf("CM");
                       break;
           }

    switch(C)
    {
           C = ((num%100)/10);

           case 1  : printf("X");
                       break;
           case 2  : printf("XX");
                       break;
           case 3  : printf("XXX");
                       break;
           case 4  : printf("XL");
                       break;
           case 5  : printf("L");
                       break;
           case 6  : printf("LI");
                       break;
           case 7  : printf("LII");
                       break;
           case 8  : printf("LIII");
                       break;
           case 9  : printf("XC");
                       break; 
    }

    switch(D)
    {
           D = num%10;

           case 1 : printf("I");
                      break;
           case 2 : printf("II");
                      break;
           case 3 : printf("III");
                      break; 
           case 4 : printf("IV");
                      break;
           case 5 : printf("V");
                      break;
           case 6 : printf("VI");
                      break;
           case 7 : printf("VII");
                      break;
           case 8 : printf("VIII");
                      break;
           case 9 : printf("IX");
                      break;      
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, got the program up and running. Grace to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your case statement includes ascii value of the numbers. Is this case 1? or case '1'. Both have different meanings.

Comment: Yup seems that I should have removed the '  ' marks. Thanks a bunch for pointing that out, got it up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

The constant-expression for a case must be the same data type as the variable in the switch, and it must be a constant or a literal.
In your case they are not the same.So please rectify that.

Comment: The expression is valid as '1' provides ascii value of 1 and is a valid integer.

Comment: yes what i meant was 1 and "1" are not one and the same .as "1" has a ascii value of 49.

Comment: The switch statement's controlling  expression has to be to an integer, as well as the  expressions of any case label has to be. A `char` literal in fact is an `int`.

Comment: @alk I agree with you . on  a side note A char literal is a short int

Comment: `sizeof  'A'` on my system (recent GCC) returns 4, where as `sizeof (short int)` returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the numbers in the switch cases, so try this one:

```
switch(A){
      case 1:    printf("M");
                 break;
      case 2:    printf("MM");
                 break;
      case 3:    printf("MMM"); 
                 break;    
}
```